# What can I call this type of member registration form?

Tags: word-request

Volunteers can request to take part in our program, and I'd like to design a form to record volunteer's registration like so:

```
John  | age 34 | male   | Program A
Alice | age 22 | female | Program B
```

Now how can I use a word to identify this form ?

I think up some words which doesn't look so well:

1. **Program Registration** (problem: register a program itself ? or people registered to program ?)
2. **Volunteer Registration** (problem: register for what ? I have another form named "Volunteer Registration" which records new volunteers registered to my group, so I don't want these 2 forms using the same name)

> ==UPDATED==
>
> A volunteer must join a volunteer team, and team leader (a senior volunteer) is responsible to look for volunteering projects and lead his team members to contribute their service. so there're two types of registration forms
>
> 1: volunteers register to a team
>
> 2: volunteers register to a project
>
> I want to identify each form and don't let people confused

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: "Volunteer Registration Form". We have to assume the registrants know what they are volunteering for.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have another form named "Volunteer Registration" which records new volunteers registered to my group, so I don't want these 2 forms using the same name

Comment: Then you have to provide more information. This is very close to proofreading, and off-topic. What are _these_ volunteers registering for? (Does your organization pay _anyone?_)

Comment: @P.E.Dant a volunteer must join a volunteer team, and team leader (a senior volunteer)  is responsible to look for volunteering projects and lead his team members to contribute their service. so there're 2 registration forms, 1: volunteers register to a team, 2: volunteers register to a project. I want to identify each form and don't make other confused

Comment: Add that information to the question by using the [edit] link. It's still proofreading, though  :( -

Comment: Easy! "Volunteers: Project Registration Form", or "Project Registration Form (Volunteers)". Either one will be understandable in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form setup looks similar to what the relational database tables might look like

> Program Registration

is information for the different programs (program name, location, etc).

> Volunteer Registration

is information for each volunteer (name, address, etc).

Then what is needed is the form (table) which potentially ties the two together

> Volunteer Program Registration

which is a many-to-many table: a volunteer can be in many programs, and a program can have many volunteers.